# How to set a fixed value of particular column to user in POST API in Django?

Tags: api, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF for creating API, using basic APIView. Below are the models and views.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class PizzaOrder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    size = models.CharField(default='MEDIUM')
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    customer_address = models.TextField()
    ordered_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Now, I need two things in that.

**First** - I want to set STATUS as 'open' in the database while ordering pizza. User isn't able to see the STATUS column while saving.

**Second** - I want to get all orders, but it should show STATUS to the user now.

**view.py**

```
class PizzaOrderView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        orders = PizzaOrder.objects.all()
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(orders, many=True)
        return Response({"orders": serializer.data})

    def post(self, request):
        orders = request.data.get('orders')
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(data=orders)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            article_saved = serializer.save()
```

What should I do to get my all two requirements?

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to save status in the database you must include it as one of the fields in your model. I would also suggest adding the `choices` enumeration so that nothing unwanted can end up in database as a status (note that you can add any other choice besides open and closed):

```
class PizzaOrder(models.Model):
    ...
    OPEN = 'open'
    CLOSED = 'closed'
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (OPEN, 'Open'),
        (CLOSED, 'Closed'),
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=OPEN)
```

Next thing to know is that the way data is presented to the user depends mostly on your serializers (would be useful if you could include those in your question aswell). So for serializing the PizzaOrder data you can use two different serializers (one which includes the status field, and one which does not):

```
class PizzaOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PizzaOrder
        fields = '__all__'

class PizzaOrderWithoutStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PizzaOrder
        fields = ['name', 'size', 'customer_name', 'customer_address', 'ordered_time']
```

Comment: when user creating a post request, then how should I restrict the user to fill the 'status', 'ordered_time' fields? The user should need to fill rest of the fields only

Answer (score 0):

you can user one serializer just just using the one serializer

```
class PizzaOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PizzaOrder
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('status',)
```

Comment: So, when user making post request, will it restrict the user to fill the 'status' field?